# How to use the KaiOS action icons?

Tags: icons, kaios

According to the [KaiOS Developer Page](https://developer.kaiostech.com/design-guide/action-icon) there are some predefined action icons which developers can use in their projects (or they can design new icons by themselves).

I'd like to use one of action icons but I don't know how.
On aforementioned page there is no any information how to use them (but there's a guideline how to make the new ones).

How to use the action icons? Has somebody already used them?
Maybe I didn't understand the information and I have to make the icons by myself?

Comment: So far I've been able to use all icons in this repository: https://github.com/why19861124/gaia-icon/tree/master/images